# invoking methods that work on main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have two different threads. the first one is the main thread that must handle the gui operations. the second one is a network thread which listens the related tcp ports. I need network thread to invoke methods in a way that they will run in the main thread. how can I achieve this without using a message queue mechanism?

Comment: How do you expect to be able to generate events on another thread *without* a message queue, and why do you not want to use a message queue?

Comment: You have to signal your main thread to call the methods somehow.  What does you GUI thread do when it's not doing GUI operations - what does it wait on?

Comment: main thread runs a 3d graphics update method. therefore, i don't want network messages to be processed under the main thread since this can reduce the graphics performance...

Comment: @Duck: main thread should only draw 3d graphics and perform gui operations, however, network messages must be processed under the network's own thread. for instance, if a chat message is received, it will be processed by the network thread and will be displayed by the main thread.

Comment: Right but they are separate threads.  The main is in charge of the gui, you don't normally want the network thread messing about.  So have the net thread signal (queue, pipe, whatever event mechanism) that there is something which requires a gui update.  Are you worried about blocking?

Comment: i'm not using a framework for networking; it runs an endless loop for reading messages and notifies the event-subscriber within the same thread. some incoming messages will have nothing to do with gui at all while others can contain a gui related event. the gui system i use is not thread safe, somehow i should carry those gui method invokes inside the main thread. it seems i'm going to use a function pointer vector to deal with this issue...

Comment: @milistroke If you really want to do this, then you are probably going to want to use std::functions or boost::functions instead of function pointers. That way you don't need to hack around a void* data argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How I would do it in your case is to is tell the other thread to schedule a function on its event queue. Arguments to that function are bound in with the function that is sent.

Like for example in the network code:

```
int result = doWork();
otherThreadsEventLoop.scheduleFunction(drawResult,result);
```

All GUI frameworks and most networking frameworks allow you to do that.

- If you are using qt, then QMetaObject::invokeMethod is what you would use.
- If you are using gtk, then q_idle_add is what you would use.
- If you are using boost::asio, then io_service.post is what you would use.
- If you are using libevent, then event_base_once is what you would use.

One issue might be the binding of additional parameters for libraries that only give you C callbacks. My suggestion is to write a "wrapper" function that allows you to pass std::functions into the callback.

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell the code running on the main thread that it needs to call your methods. No matter how you implement this you will essentially have some kind of message queue. You'll have to be more specific about your actual requirements so that we can suggest a message queue mechanism appropriate for your case.